# how to configure UIImage view for iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was made the project for iPhone which contain UIImage. Now I have to implement same project 
for iPad . So what is size of image which can i used. also tell me if there is any another code for for page size as it was in iPhone like CGRect like that. also provide some code to adjust image from landscape to portrait.

Thanks

Comment: since i am new i didn't understood at beigining. but now i understood

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of iPad screen : 1024*768

To get full screen frame : `CGRect mainFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];`

To check for orientation look at thoose functions :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```